# How do I get Emacs to recognize my python 3 virtual environment

Tags: python

My system is macOS and I have both python 2 and 3 installed. I am currently working on a side project for which I want to use Django 1.8 and python 3.4.

I have created a virtual environment with the python 3 command `pyvenv venv` in the parent folder of my project (I prefer to have my python project folders to be self contained).

At the moment, I cannot get Emacs to recognise and therefore limit all code related assist to the virtual environment.

In addition, is it possible to setup per-project settings such that I can have different projects use different python versions and environment? The ideal scenario will be, when I change into a project directory and start Emacs, it will pick all it's environment settings from that project directory according to some local settings file.

Comment: I don't know the difference between `pyvenv` and `virtualevn`, which I'm familiar with, but can't you just bind `python-shell-virtualenv-root` to the right path?  Either via a file variables or dir variables.  E.g. `# -*- python-shell-virtualenv-root: "../env" -*-`.  If this does not work with `pyvenv` please fill a bug report, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a package called pyvenv to manage virtual environmnets in emacs. Try installing it with

```
`M-x package-install RET pyvenv RET`
```

Now You to activate env in your emacs, You can run

```
M-x pyvenv-activate RET <path-to-venv>
```

Checkout: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv

For per project management, You can use hooks to activate venv automatically.

Comment: i have do it, but i can't type `pyvenv-activate` :-(

Comment: Does anyone know if it works with `dap-debug`?

Answer (score 5):

I am using https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv as well, and I set it up like so:

```
(use-package pyvenv
  :ensure t
  :config
  (pyvenv-mode 1))
```

This `pyvenv-mode 1` part is essential. This will automatically make the venv activate when the variable pyvenv-activate is changed.

So, now leverage `.dir-locals.el` to set that for my projects.

```
((nil . ((pyvenv-activate . "~/repos/my_proj/.venv"))))
```

Now when I open a file in my project, that virtual environment is activated!